# Xpath for specific child element of a parent element which is not distinguished by class?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping

The html snippet is like this:

```
<div class="busi-attr">

           <p><span class="attrName">Min. Order: </span>1 Piece</p>
           <p><span class="attrName">Supply Ability: </span>10,000&nbsp;&nbsp;Piece/Pieces  per  Month</p>
    </div>
```

I only want the second `<p>` element that is amount 10,000 and nothing else, how do i do that? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try xpath with a list comprehension that checks the text value of an element:

```
span=[x for x in yourwebelement.xpath('//span[@class="attrName"]') if 'supply ability' in x.text.lower()][0]
```

This is only the span of course, but all you need now is the parent

```
p=span.xpath('.//parent::p')[0]
```

I think the span block stops you from getting the text value of p, so let's get all the text minus whatever is in the span.

```
text=[x for x in p.itertext() if x != span.text]
```

Comment: what is yourwebelement here?

Comment: It's the object the webpage is loaded into. Didn't know what you were using only saw Python, so gave you a solution that would work with the lxml module and should be easy to modify.